# Reviewing not available on mobile application?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, mobile-web

Unless I am missing something, reviewing is not available on mobile application.

It seems to me that reviewing would be a contribution that would be most suited to mobile, because less textual input and research is usually required. I find answering and asking questions is considerably more awkward on mobile, because of the clumsy input, and web browser interface, but sometimes, my mobile is all I have available.

Is there a good reason it is not available, or is it an implementation issue?  (or am I just blind, and don't see it in the UI)?

Comment: Can the inclusion of this feature on mobile come with "Don't review and drive" bumper stickers?

Comment: @HaveNo: Why did the title change to "mobile **application**"?  I thought this was about the mobile **web**.

Comment: @NisseEngström because on mobile application you can't use review queue but on mobile web you can using the full site option

Comment: No you can't. You _can_ on the **full site**.

Comment: Full site on mobile...yes you can. See answer...

Comment: @MuertoExcobito: Did you mean mobile **web page** or **mobile application**? I think your original question _and_ the tag description need clarification..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. Review feature is not available on Mobile application.

Review queues are only available from the full site. The mobile site is not optimized for the review queues and the mobile apps both rely on the API which does not [currently] allow access to the review queues.

However, you can go right bottom side in mobile application, here you can find "full site" option. And then you can use review feature on mobile.